# Why does VSCode's Agda plugin not recognize shortcuts?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts, agda

I'm having trouble using shortcuts provided by the Agda plugin for VSCode. The problem is that certain commands that are registered inside the shortcuts do not work.

For instance, when trying to refine a hole, I press CTRL+C then CTRL+R. VSCode, at the bottom, says that this is not a valid command despite being the exact command that this shortcut uses. I have to, instead, open the Command Palette and type the command from there.

Answer (score 1):

Please see [the comment on this issue](https://github.com/banacorn/agda-mode-vscode/issues/132#issuecomment-1431464866) on GitHub, which provides a workaround.

Following the instructions there, I replaced each occurrence of `agdaMode` with `editorLangId == agda` in the `keybindings` section of the file `package.json`. (The default location of this file on Windows is `C:\Users\[YourUserName]\.vscode\extensions\[ExtensionName]`.) This worked for me.